# Drawing arrows in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add the arrows as shown in the picture. I an new to latex. Can someone tell the code? i am using beamer class
[image: This was made using powerpoint]

It was made in powerpoint.

Comment: There is probably a way to do this in tikz (I don't know it though since I don't know tikz). Another option might be to save an arrow image as a pdf file and include it using `\includegraphics`. You could get arrows pointing in different directions by rotating the graphic using the optional arguments for `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As JohnReed said, you could use TikZ for this: In the `shapes.arrows` library, there's a very customisable arrow shape that would be well suited for this.

In the example below, I've defined a TikZ style using `\tikzset` that sets the options common to the up and down arrows, and two maros `\arrowup` and `\arrowdown` that use an inline `\tikz` command to draw the arrows using the new style, only changing the rotation of the arrow. If you want to change the colour or thickness of the arrow, for example, you only need to edit the style, the macros stay the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}


\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        draw,
        fill=orange,
        single arrow,
        minimum height=3.5ex,
        single arrow head extend=1ex
    }
}
\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90] {};}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
Thermal Grashof number& \arrowup\\[1ex]
Velocity & \arrowup\arrowdown\\[1ex]
Temperature & \arrowdown\\[1ex]
Solutal boundary layer thickness & \arrowdown\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```