# Insert graphs and text side by side

Tags: beamer, floats, subfloats, arrows

I wanna know how can I draw graphs and arrows with text, side by side in Beamer as shown in the figure of this question
[Drawing arrows in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61507/14577)

Can someone post the code?

Comment: Do you need to reproduce the same frame with 3 graphs?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes

Comment: You can use `minipage`s to contain figures/text that needs to be placed side by side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example, based on [Drawing arrows in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61507/drawing-arrows-in-beamer#61512), that uses the `columns` environment. The final output is:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=4.75cm,compat=newest} % to fix the width and pgfplots version
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=0.4}} % to reduce mark size
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        draw,
        fill=orange,
        single arrow,
        minimum height=3.5ex,
        single arrow head extend=0.8ex
    }
}
\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz [baseline=-0.5ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=90] {};}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz [baseline=-1ex]{\node [myarrow,rotate=-90] {};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My graphs}
\begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
  % Text
  \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{rc}
  Thermal Grashof number & \arrowup\\[1ex]
  Velocity & \arrowup\arrowdown\\[1ex]
  Temperature & \arrowdown\\[1ex]
  Solutal boundary layer thickness & \arrowdown\\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{column}
 \hspace{0.15\textwidth} % needed to compensate the arrows space
 \begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
  % Graphs
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
   yticklabel style={font=\tiny}]
   \addplot {sqrt(x)}; 
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
   yticklabel style={font=\tiny}]
   \addplot {ln(x)}; 
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
   yticklabel style={font=\tiny}]
   \addplot[blue,mark=none,
    domain=-4:4,samples=501]
   {sqrt(abs(x))};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Disclaimer**

The approach is strongly dependent on the `theme` chosen; `theme`s with a sidebar, i.e. PaloAlto, reduces the available space so the dimensions of the graphs and/or of the `column` environments should be reconsidered.