# Beamer overlay images in column environment

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a frame with the two columns, one for an image, and one for itemized text. For example,

```
\frame{\frametitle{hello} 

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=40mm]{pic1.png}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item statement 1
      \item statement 2
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
​  \end{columns}


}
```

I want to specify an overlay, such that `pic1` appears along with statement 1 and `pic2` appears with statement 2. How do could I do this?

Comment: I think you can have a look to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63283/figures-and-blocks-in-the-same-slide). The difference is that you should add an overlay to `includegraphics`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the fact that both `\includegraphics` and `\item` are overlay-aware, you can do somthing like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{hello} 
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics<1>[width=40mm]{cat}
      \includegraphics<2>[width=40mm]{ctanlion}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1> statement 1
      \item<2> statement 2
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
​  \end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: Excellent minimum working example. All I had to do was save the *cat* and *ctanlion* as actual graphic files and it got me over the rut I was stuck in for minutes. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Gonzalo, I am trying to do something similar where the text is already present and I am adding the picture in the `\onslide<2-> {}`. But this changes the vertical alignment of the text. I can share an MWE but I am not sure if a similar question exists. Can you point me in the right direction?