# Left column with a figure to the right (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, floats, two-column

I can't understand how to make a column to the left with a figure to the right:

Here is one example of what I did:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    ...
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
 \begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{\textwidth}
 Composition:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item first item
 \end{itemize}
 \end{column} 
 \end{columns}

 \begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{fig} 
 \caption{}
 \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
```

The figure compares in the middle, how flush it to the right?

Comment: Related: [Insert graphs and text side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62482/13304).

Answer (score 4):

This is a MWE that puts a box in the right column. I have kept the `\includegraphics` where it should be. In your code you started the `columns` environment but didi not define a second column where you could put your figure.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}

\begin{columns}
 \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  Composition:
  \begin{itemize}
   \item first item
  \end{itemize}
 \end{column}

 \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{picture}(2,2)
   \put(0,0){\dashbox{0.2}(2,2)}
  \end{picture}
 %\includegraphics[\textwidth]{fig}
 \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can scale the columns widths to suit your needs.