# How to draw full-screen icon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, icon

I'm trying to recreate this figure, but unfortunately I no longer have access to its source material:

[image: original]

So far I've figured out how to draw the rectangle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}   

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\definecolor{viewbutton_border}{RGB}{113, 145, 203}
\definecolor{viewbutton_top}{RGB}{143, 171, 217}
\definecolor{viewbutton_bottom}{RGB}{115, 147, 204}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (button) at (0,0) [
        rectangle,
        top color=viewbutton_top, 
        bottom color=viewbutton_bottom,
        draw=viewbutton_border, 
        rounded corners=0.5mm, 
        line width=0.4mm,
        minimum width=1.72cm,
        minimum height=1.37cm,
    ] {};
    % how to draw the arrows?
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

And now I'm lost figuring out how to draw these arrows with TikZ inside the rectangle. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Here you can find ideas for the arrow shape: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61507

Comment: Why not just use [an existing icon from FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/arrows-alt/)?

Comment: @Werner in latex/pdf document? is that possible?

Comment: @Korijn: Yes; [here's a minimal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztiq0.png).

Comment: Just curios, why do you want to draw this? :-)

Comment: Well.. it's a long story. :) At work we produce PDFs with pdflatex, with form elements and 3D scenes, all tied together using JS. One of the buttons enlarges a 3D viewport to match the screen. And, we lost the source artwork! So as part of a refactor I replaced the bitmaps with tikz. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basic idea is to use a `path picture` to draw the arrows over the background of the node. Inside the path picture a special node `path picture bounding box` is available which is a rectangle which covers the extent of the node path.

The `calc` library is used to calculate start and end points points along the diagonals from the center of the `path picture bounding box` to each of its corners and also to calculate the height and width of the node. The minimum of the height and width is used as a basis for the thickness of the line and the dimensions of the arrowhead. Then the arrow is drawn using the `Triangle` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library.

I have also assumed that the border of the button should scale with the size of the button, which is passed as a parameter to the `view button` style.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\definecolor{vbborder}{RGB}{93, 120, 190}
\definecolor{vbtop}{RGB}{143, 171, 217}
\definecolor{vbbottom}{RGB}{115, 147, 204}
\tikzset{view button/.style={
  shape=rectangle,  
  minimum width={#1}, minimum height={(#1)*1.37/1.72},
  line width={(#1)/20}, rounded corners={(#1)/5},
  top color=vbtop, 
  bottom color=vbbottom, 
  draw=vbborder,
  path picture={
    \foreach \i in {45,135,225,315}
      \draw let \p1=(path picture bounding box.center),
        \p2=(path picture bounding box.\i),
        \n1={min(abs(\x2-\x1),abs(\y2-\y1))} in
        [white, line width=\n1/4, -{Triangle[width=\n1*.75,length=\n1*.375]}]
        ($(\p1)!0.175!(\p2)$) -- ($(\p1)!0.7!(\p2)$);
}},
view button/.default=1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (v);
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
  \node [view button=\i*10pt, above=5pt of v] (v) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very impressive and uses many techniques that I'm unfamiliar with. Would you care to explain the general principle? I see some control flow and use of `path picture`... how does it work?

Comment: @Korijn see the updated answer.

Comment: This answer taught me a lot about Tikz, and solved the problem perfectly, retaining the background gradient. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I draw some squares like this.  First, the background blue rectangle.  Above that, a white square.  On top of that, four squares, tilted at 45°, so that their tips will fall on the x or y axis.  Last a blue square in the middle it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bborder}{RGB}{113, 145, 203}
\definecolor{bbottom}{RGB}{115, 147, 204}
\definecolor{btop}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Draw the outer blue rectangle/square
  \draw[ultra thick, rounded corners, draw=bborder, fill=bbottom]
  (-10,-8.1) -- (-10,8.1) -- (10,8.1) -- (10,-8.1);
  % Draw the white square
  \draw[fill=btop,draw=btop]
  (-6.3,-6.3) -- (-6.3,6.3) -- (6.3,6.3) -- (6.3,-6.3) -- cycle;
  % Draw four squares, each tilted at 45° filled in blue
  \draw[draw=bbottom, fill=bbottom]
  (0,-7.9) -- (-3.1,-4.8) -- (0,-1.7) -- (3.1,-4.8) -- cycle;
  \draw[draw=bbottom, fill=bbottom]
  (0,7.9) -- (-3.1,4.8) -- (0,1.7) -- (3.1,4.8) -- cycle;
  \draw[draw=bbottom, fill=bbottom]
  (-7.9,0) -- (-4.8,-3.1) -- (-1.7,0) -- (-4.8,3.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[draw=bbottom, fill=bbottom]
  (7.9,0) -- (4.8,-3.1) -- (1.7,0) -- (4.8,3.1) -- cycle;
  % A last square on top in the middle, again in blue
  \draw[draw=bbottom,fill=bbottom]
  (-2.5,0) -- (0,-2.5) -- (2.5,0) -- (0,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is my result.  Please, polish my code to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Nice out-of-the-box thinking! Unfortunately, I really want the gradient in the background to remain visible and I'm not sure how I would accomplish that with this approach. It looks very pretty though!

Comment: @Korijn: Oh yes.  You are right.  Bear with me, this was my second attempt on TkiZ.  It was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 11):

A short code with `pstricks`, compilable with `pdflatex` if you add the switch `--enable-write18` for MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` for TeX Live and MacTeX:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\BigArrow{%
\psset{unit=1mm, linecolor=white, linejoin=1}%
\pnode(13,0){S}
\pnodes{A}(0,2)(8,2)(8,5)
\pnodes{B}(0,-2)(8,-2)(8,-5)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid](A0)(A1)(A2)(S)(B2)(B1)(B0)}%

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psframe[unit=2cm, linewidth=3pt, linecolor=SteelBlue3, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=LightSteelBlue3, framearc=0.1](-1,-1)(1,1)%
\multido{\i = 45 + 90}{4}{\rput{\i}(0.4; \i) {\BigArrow}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If possible I would prefer to stick with utilities that are "available by default". It's easier to deploy in automated systems. I'm also unfamiliar with pstrick so a Tikz solution would be preferable to me.

Comment: The switch is necessary only if you compile with `pdflatex`. Otherwise, you can remove loading of `auto-pst-pdf`, and either: – follow the  classic `latex->dvips->pstopdf` way,  or – compile with `xelatex`.